# More efficient way to concatenate strings base on two lists

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

Was wondering if there is a faster way to generate a string base on two list of strings.  For example I have

```
e = ['1','2','3']
op = ['+','*']
```

And i would like to get `"1+2*3"`

Assuming I have to do this a thousand times or so, with different sizes of arrays.  Is there a faster way to get the answer I want?

I tried a few ways, see below.  From the options I tried, it seems using `+=` is better.  Was wondering if there is a faster approach.

Edit: (Added a couple of the suggestions as well)

```
import itertools

def usingPlus(e,sign):
    temp = ""
    for num, operator in zip(e, sign):
        temp += num
        temp += operator

    temp += e[-1]
    return temp

def joinArray(e, sign):
    temp = [ num+op for num, op in zip(e,sign) ]
    temp.append(e[-1])
    return "".join(temp)

def stringJoin(e, sign):
    temp = ""
    for num, operator in zip(e, sign):
        temp.join(num)
        temp.join(operator)

    temp.join(e[-1])
    return temp

def zip_longest(e, op):
    arry = [x+y for x,y in itertools.zip_longest(e,op,fillvalue="")]
    return "".join(arry)

def build_string(e,op):
    s=""
    for i in range(len(op)):
        s+=e[i]
        s+=op[i]
    s+=e[-1]
    return s

for i in range(3000000):
    e = ['1','2','3']
    op = ['+','*']

    usingPlus(e,op)               ## total ~2.7 sec
    #joinArray(e,op)              ## total ~3.4 sec
    #stringJoin(e,op)             ## total ~6.4 sec
    #zip_longest(e,op)            ## total ~4.1 sec
    #build_string(e,op)           ## total ~3.2 sec
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that concatenating strings is O(n) whereas appending to a list is O(1), so I would expect joinArray to start being much quicker as the lengths of the lists increase.

Comment: just to what has been tried this takes about 13 seconds

for i in range(3000000):
 string = e[randint(0,len(e)-1)] + op[randint(0,len(op)-1)] + e[randint(0,len(e)-1)] + op[randint(0,len(op)-1)] + e[randint(0,len(e)-1)]

Answer (score 0):

With the given input += does seem the quickest.
This version shaves about 10% off of your timings.

```
import time
def build_string(e,op):
    s=""
    for i in range(len(op)):
        s+=e[i]
        s+=op[i]
    s+=e[-1]
e=['1','3','5','7']
op=['-','+','*']
start = time.time()
for x in range(3000000):
    build_string(e,op)
end = time.time()
print end-start
```

I didn't include a `return s` as neither did `usingPlus`

```
def build_string(e,op):
    s=""
    for idx,val in enumerate(op):
        s+=e[idx]
        s+=val
    s+=e[-1]
```

Shaves a tiny bit more time off on my box

Comment: Yea i forgot the return there, but it should have it.  For my computer this function actually takes 3.2 sec.  Its possible your computer is faster.  Anyways, seems that += is still the best for what I need

Answer (score 0):

Regards User,

If I may contribute, in the case of : when the input is two lists of strings, each element is a string with length 1.

The function below might give an idea. It is very simple though.

```
def parity_string(x,y):
z=x+y; z[0::2]=x; z[1::2]=y; z=str(z);
z=z[2::5];
return z
```

The idea is first make the corresponding list version, then convert it to string. The final part would be analyzing the pattern of the final string object.

If the inputs are like your example, the desired characters in the final string will have index sequence (2,7,12,...). Then take only the values with those indexes.

```
z=z[2::5];
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Elements in the string can be longer than length 1, but thanks for the input.